# Junit test for returning vowels in a user input string?

Tags: java, string, junit

I created some methods for setting string, getting string and getting vowels as follows. How do I write a JUnit test case for `getVowels()`?

In the test case, should I not state what the correct answer is? Since the user can input any string, how do I make Junit pass or fail the test case? What do I enter in `assertEquals` as in the last line of the test case?

```
package sec.vowels;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyStrings implements MyStringInterface {
public String str;
public char c;
// Sets the value of the current string
    public void setString(String str) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
        str = input.next();
        input.close();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    // Returns the current string
    public String getString() {
        return str;
        }
    public String getVowels(){
        for (int i=0; i <str.length();i++){
            c = str.charAt(i);      
            if((str.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'u')){
                }
            System.out.println(c);
            }
        return str;
    }
}

//test case. 
    public void testGetVowels() {
        MyStrings test = new MyStrings();
        String results = test.getVowels();
        assertEquals("");
```

Comment: Unit tests should be repeatable. This means that you usually don't want to rely on user input.

Comment: Since the method `getVowels()` accepts no arguments and returns a string, that's all you can test...

Comment: What is the purpose of `getVowels()`? What is it supposed to do? You need to understand this in order to formulate tests for it. Describing the requirements to us will help you understand better.

Comment: getVowels() Returns a string that consists of all and only the vowels in the current string. Thanks for your help

Comment: Nope. It just prints the vowels. It returns the full string.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, your `setString()` is doing too many tasks in a single method. This might be one reason that you are having trouble testing it. Personally, I would rewrite it as

```
public void setString(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}
```

Now `setString()` doesn't care where the `String` comes from. In a JUnit test, you can use a fixed String literal. In a interactive program, `main()` can ask the user for a String (similar to how you do it now) and then pass it to `setString()`.

This kind of uncoupling is ideal in many situations.

Another suggestion is to replace the repeated calls to `str.getCharAt(i)` with `c` since you are already storing that result in a variable. Also, `c` should be declared locally to `getVowels()` since it is not used in any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend following the advice in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634937/474189) to refactor your code to make it testable. I would suggest adding a package-private method:

```
void setString(String str) {
  this.str = str;
}
```

Then, you can use [JUnit's parameterized test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm) construct to test multiple values efficiently. In the example below, I construct some expected values and test the class with it. It currently fails, so perhaps you can use the test to fix your problems.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyStringsTest {

  private final String input;
  private final String expected;

  public MyStringsTest(String input, String expected) {
    this.input = input;
    this.expected = expected;
  }

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> makeParams() {
    List<Object[]> result =
        Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
            // These are pairs of (input, expected output)
            new Object[] { "abcd", "a" },  // <----------------- Fails
            new Object[] { "aeiou", "aeiou" }, // <------------- Passes
            new Object[] { "AEIOU", "AEIOU" }, // <------------- Passes
            new Object[] { "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz", "" } // <--- Fails 
        });

    return result;
  }

  @Test
  public void testValidVowels() throws Exception {
    MyStrings ms = new MyStrings();
    ms.setString(input);
    assertEquals(expected, ms.getVowels());
  }
}
```